# when using backbone.js to create extended model the validate doesn't work

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I been trying to get my head around backbone.js and I just try to follow on a tutorial at https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validating-models/ on how to validate models, but for some reason my code just don't validate

any idea of why it might be?

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 30,
    occupation: 'worker'
  },

  validate: function (attrs) {
    if (attrs.age <= 0) {
        return "age must be positive";
    }

    if (!attrs.name) {
        return "every person must have a name";
    }
  },

  work: function () {
    return this.get('name') + ' is working.';
  }
});
```

Can anyone please help? is anything wrong with the code?

Comment: What data are you using to validate? The defaults are valid according to your rules. If you use console.log to check age and name, what do you see?

Comment: This question has been asked several times this week. You have to use `{validate:true}` option.
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

Answer (score 1):

Backbone recently changed the circumstances under which validation occurs. It used to occur, by default, on `model.set()` but now only occurs (by default) on `model.save()`. You need to either explicitly call `model.validate()` or, as another commenter noted, pass `{validate: true}` options to `model.set()`.

I'm guessing that the tutorial you reference was written before the change to `model.set()` behaviour.

Comment: Was facing the same issues. This helped :)